# Executing Multiple Sequelize JS model query methods with Promises - Node

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, mean-stack, sequelize-cli

I am having a problem retrieving data from database using sequelize js. I am new to NODEJS. I don't know if Promise and Promise.all are built in functions 
So i install and require npm promise in my code too.
Below is my code.

```
var Promise = require('promise');

var user_profile = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    db.user_profile.findOne({
        where: {
            profile_id: new_profile_id
        }
    }).then(user => {
        console.log('Summary Result User found.');
        resolve(user);
    });
});

var all_reports = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    db.report.all().then(reports => {
        console.log('Summary Result Reports found.');
        resolve(reports);
    });
});

var report_details = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    db.report_detail.findAll({
        where: {
            profile_id: new_profile_id
        }
    }).then(report_details => {
        console.log('Summary Result Report Details found');
        resolve(report_details);
    });
});

var all_promises = Promise.all([user_profile, all_reports, report_details]).then(function(data) {
    console.log('**********COMPLETE RESULT****************');
    console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('**********ERROR RESULT****************');
    console.log(err);
});
```

I want to get the data of all three queries. When i run them individually I get the data but when i run them in Promise.all I only get user_profile data and other two remain **undefined**
I have also tried nested these queries with .then but result is still same I only get one query data other two remain **undefined**

**with then chainging**

```
var results = [];
var new_profile_id = req.params.profile_id;
console.log(new_profile_id);
db.user_profile.findOne({
    where: {
        profile_id: new_profile_id
    }
}).then(user => {
    console.log('Summary Result User found.');
    results.push(user.dataValues);
    return user;
}).then(user => {
    db.report.all().then(reports => {
        console.log('Summary Result Reports found.');
        results.push(reports.dataValues);
        return reports
    });
}).then(reports => {
    db.report_detail.findAll({
        where: {
            profile_id: new_profile_id
        }
    }).then(report_details => {
        console.log('Summary Result Report Details found');
        results.push(report_details.dataValues);
        console.log('**********COMPLETE RESULT****************');
        console.log(results);
        console.log('**********COMPLETE RESULT****************');
        return report_details;
    });
});
```

can someone please help me in this concept what i am doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The latest version of Node.js already supports `Promise` natively, so does `Sequelize`. This means no need to require `promise` separately.

The following code is based on yours.

```
const user_profile = db.user_profile.findOne({
    where: {
        profile_id: new_profile_id
    }
});

const all_reports = db.report.all();

const report_details = db.report_detail.findAll({
    where: {
        profile_id: new_profile_id
    }
});

Promise
    .all([user_profile, all_reports, report_details])
    .then(responses => {
        console.log('**********COMPLETE RESULTS****************');
        console.log(responses[0]); // user profile
        console.log(responses[1]); // all reports
        console.log(responses[2]); // report details
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('**********ERROR RESULT****************');
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Notice that there is no need to wrap Sequelize calls with `Promise` becasue Sequelize already returns promises. This way you only need to have one `catch` in the last `Promise.all()` which you were missing in all calls. What this means is that if any calls were to fail, a corresponding `resolve` would never be called. This, in turn, means that the last `Promise.all()` would also never be called. This is why it is good to handle all errors at the end once, unless there are some custom error handling requirements.

Comment: @Eye Can you help me?. I have a doubt in using sequelize in node js. I couldn't build the large logic with sequelize. Can you send your mail, I'll send my code.

my email: sakkeer@brigita.co

Comment: Really nice way to get the responses. I just used in on my projects and works well, thanks!